# Overwrite an instance attribute conditionally

Tags: ruby, class, instance, instance-variables

I have a class that I'm trying to determine the output based on the creation input.

```
class MyCommand
  attr_accessor :command

  def initialize(command = nil)
    @command = command
  end

  # @return Boolean
  def global?
    @command.start_with?('--global')
  end
end
```

This works just fine like so:

```
foo = MyCommand.new('hello')
foo.command #=> "hello"
foo.global? #=> false
```

However, when I pass in my conditions, I get some good, some not-so-good results:

```
bar = MyCommand.new('--global world')
bar.global? #=> true
bar.command #=> "--global world"
```

Namely, the `command` is including my condition.

I've tried creating another method to sub out `--global` from any command that has it, but then I get slightly different results:

```
bar.command = 'world'
bar.command #=> "world"
bar.global? #=> false
```

But that will mutate the current state of `bar`.

How might I go about making this class and methods behave so that the `global?` flag remains even after a command is changed?

Even better, can I implement all of the changes within the `global?` method only - thereby minimizing my impact on the class change overall?

Comment: Do you want `@command` to be `--global world` but return `world` when you call `barr.command` or do you actually want `@command` to be `world` when the input is `--global world`?

Comment: @Joseph I think I want `bar.command` to return `world`, but for `bar.global?` to return `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During `initialize`, you could strip out `--global` when setting `@command` and you could assign `@global` to true or false and then edit `@global?` to return the value:

```
class MyCommand
  attr_accessor :command

  def initialize(command = '')
    @command = command.gsub('--global ','')
    @global = command.start_with?('--global') ? true : false
  end

  # @return Boolean
  def global?
    @global
  end
end
```

Note that the `gsub` is going to remove '--global ' whether it is in the begginning, middle, or end of `command` and it is assuming that it is always followed by a trailing space, so if you aren't sure of your inputs you'll need something a bit more robust to process `command`.

P.S. Just realized this will not work if `command` is `nil`, so changed default to empty string. If you really need it to be `nil`, some extra checking will be required (but unfortunately I gotta log off now).

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using more of this approach, where I pass in the global state to `initialize` and act on it later.